# Suppose $A ⊆ R$ and for each $ϵ > 0$ let $I_ϵ = [a ∈ R : (a − ϵ , a + ϵ ) ⊆ A]$. Is it true that $A = ∪_{ϵ>0}I_ϵ$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $A ⊆ R$ and for each $ϵ > 0$ let $I_ϵ = [a ∈ R : (a − ϵ , a + ϵ ) ⊆ A]$. Is it true that $A = ∪_{ϵ>0}I_ϵ$?

I want to say no, because $∪_{ϵ>0}I_ϵ$ does not contain $a - ∈$ or $a + ∈$, but $A$ could contain them because they are real numbers.

Comment: You may note that $\bigcup_{\epsilon > 0} I_\epsilon = \mathring A$, i.e. the [interior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_%28topology%29) of $A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true for open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ under the standard topology. You can take the definition of an open set $U$ to be one where, for each point $a\in U$, you can find an open interval centered at $a$ such that $a\in I_{\epsilon}\subset U$. You can then take the set to be the union of such intervals.

For non-open sets this doesn't work. Just take the singleton for an example. Your $I_{\epsilon}$ will be empty, contradicting equality.

Simple examples of open sets include open intervals: $(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$ where $a<b$. A non-open set is $(a,b]\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What is the singleton?

Comment: @Chris The singleton is any one point set. Have you had topology?

Comment: No, I've never taken that. This is for my Introductory Proofs class, so I don't have much experience with many mathematical topics yet.

Comment: @Chris it's a good thing you're already thinking about these things! My answer is self-containted either way, and it is thorough and complete. Ask if anything is unclear.

Comment: Yeah, we just jumped in to this kind of stuff and it caught me completely offguard. Let me see if I can get this right: If $A$ contains only a single point, it's impossible for $I_ϵ$ to contain only that one point because it is an open interval?

Comment: Yes, $I_{\epsilon}$ forces you to include points around any point in the set $A$ you are considering. But what if the set $A$ only has one point, i.e. $A={a}$? Then all those $I_{\epsilon}$ sets are empty. So $A$ cannot possibly be the union of them, since $A$ is non-empty.

Comment: On the other hand, if you have a special type of set, called an open set $U$, where at each point you can find neighbors also in the set, then you can express that special set as the union of your $I_{\epsilon}$ sets, since each point, by definition, has **some** epsilon such that $I_{\epsilon}\subset U$.

Answer (score 1):

No. The union can be a lot smaller: take $A = \mathbb{Q}$, say. Then the union will be $\emptyset$, as all intervals contain irrational numbers.

Comment: Wouldn't each $I_\epsilon$ be empty? $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)$ always contains an irrational number ...

Comment: @CarlHeckman you're right of course. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

If $a\in\cup_{\epsilon>0}I_\epsilon$ then $a\in \{a\in\mathbb{R}: (a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\subseteq A)\}$ thus $(a-\epsilon,a+\epsilon)\subseteq A$, and hence $a\in A$. Thus we may conclude that $A\supseteq \cup_{\epsilon>0}I_\epsilon$.

However this subset may be strict. For instance let $A= \{0\}$. Then $I_{\epsilon} = \emptyset$, thus $\cup_{\epsilon>0}I_\epsilon=\emptyset$.

So the answer is: No.

Comment: So if $A$ only contained one number, it would be impossible for $I_ϵ$ to have only that one number because it is an open interval?

Comment: Yes. If $A$ is a singleton then $A$ does not contain any interval, which is required in order for $I_{\epsilon} $ to be non-empty.

Comment: You actually prove the reverse inclusion!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma , sure, typo, thanks....

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $A = [p, q]$, then $p \not\in I_\epsilon\;\forall\;\epsilon > 0$, hence $p \not\in \cup_{\epsilon > 0}I_\epsilon$.

Same will be true for any $A$ with boundary points. Since $\mathring{A} = A \backslash \partial A$, remaining $A$'s have to be open. Let $A$ be open. Then $a \in A \implies \exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $(a - \epsilon, a + \epsilon) \subseteq A \implies a \in I_\epsilon$, therefore $A \subseteq \cup_{\epsilon > 0} I_\epsilon$. The other containment is trivial. Hence equality holds.

In summary, the statement is true if and only if $A$ is open.